# Finding the source code for a Python module

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm as my editor and seemingly it doesn't behave well with [certain sub-modules](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13124) namely `numpy.random.normal`. Not to be disheartened I tracked down where `numpy.random` lives to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random`.

I can't see any instance of normal. There's the definition for it in `__init__.py` but no actual code for me to copy into a new class for my project.

Am I looking in the wrong place for the code?

Comment: Why do you want to see the source? What is the problem you are having? These functions are implemented in C, see e.g. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c#L103

Comment: Whenever I try to import it into PyCharm using `noise = numpy.random.normal(0, power_noise, len(self.data))` it tells me it cannot find the reference. If I open a terminal, however, I can use the normal function as I desire.

Comment: This looks like a PyCharm bug (indeed, their bugtracker lists several bugs like this). It's a commercial product, so take your problem to the software's developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out, where a package is located by doing so:

```
import numpy.random
print numpy.random.__file__
```

In your case, it seems that the main parts of the module are implemented  in C. You can see in the directory, that there is a file "mtrand.so" located in it. This is a shared object that was created from C sources, which are typically not delivered with the runtime package. The Python system can load such shared objects at runtime, when you import the module/package.

Comment: So even though it gives me a warning before I run it, whenever I run the actual program it should behave as desired?

Comment: Can you give the complete error message? I am not familiar with PyCharm. Could it be, that the system has different PYTHONPATH? Is it using the same Python version???

Comment: normal is definitively implemented in mtrand.so on my system. I don't know, what is with your PyCharm system -- it must have something to do with PyCharm or PyCharm is accessing a different version of Python.