# How to find method implementation in numpy repo

Tags: python, numpy, github, random

I just read about the Box-Mueller approach for generating normal random variables and want to see if the method in numpy python uses the same approach. To this end, I want to look at the source code. I've been combing through the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663) but haven't had any luck yet. The folder "random" seems to not have the code I'm interested in. In particular, I want the code that is invoked when calling -

```
import numpy as np
rand = np.random.normal(size=10)
```

Is anyone able to point me to this part of the code and generally explain how to effectively perform these kinds of searches.

EDIT: The line of code below isn't of much help in this case since it just points to the **init**.py file that doesn't have too much in it.

```
print(numpy.random.__file__)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the source code for a Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649802/finding-the-source-code-for-a-python-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the code you are looking for is here:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/464f79eb1d05bf938d16b49da1c39a4e02506fa3/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1551

As you can see, it's located under `random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx`. If you are wondering about `.pyx`: Cython states:

> "A .pyx file is compiled by Cython to a .c file, containing the code of a Python extension module. The .c file is compiled by a C compiler to a .so file (or .pyd on Windows) which can be imported directly into a Python session."

You were looking for the definition of `normal` so I searched for `"def normal"`.

Here's the code at that link:

```
def normal(self, loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None):
    """
    normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
    Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.
    The probability density function of the normal distribution, first
    derived by De Moivre and 200 years later by both Gauss and Laplace
    independently [2]_, is often called the bell curve because of
    its characteristic shape (see the example below).
    The normal distributions occurs often in nature.  For example, it
    describes the commonly occurring distribution of samples influenced
    by a large number of tiny, random disturbances, each with its own
    unique distribution [2]_.
    Parameters
    ----------
    loc : float or array_like of floats
        Mean ("centre") of the distribution.
    scale : float or array_like of floats
        Standard deviation (spread or "width") of the distribution.
    size : int or tuple of ints, optional
        Output shape.  If the given shape is, e.g., ``(m, n, k)``, then
        ``m * n * k`` samples are drawn.  If size is ``None`` (default),
        a single value is returned if ``loc`` and ``scale`` are both scalars.
        Otherwise, ``np.broadcast(loc, scale).size`` samples are drawn.
    Returns
    -------
    out : ndarray or scalar
        Drawn samples from the parameterized normal distribution.
    See Also
    --------
    scipy.stats.norm : probability density function, distribution or
        cumulative density function, etc.
    Notes
    -----
    The probability density for the Gaussian distribution is
    .. math:: p(x) = \\frac{1}{\\sqrt{ 2 \\pi \\sigma^2 }}
                     e^{ - \\frac{ (x - \\mu)^2 } {2 \\sigma^2} },
    where :math:`\\mu` is the mean and :math:`\\sigma` the standard
    deviation. The square of the standard deviation, :math:`\\sigma^2`,
    is called the variance.
    The function has its peak at the mean, and its "spread" increases with
    the standard deviation (the function reaches 0.607 times its maximum at
    :math:`x + \\sigma` and :math:`x - \\sigma` [2]_).  This implies that
    `numpy.random.normal` is more likely to return samples lying close to
    the mean, rather than those far away.
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] Wikipedia, "Normal distribution",
           https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution
    .. [2] P. R. Peebles Jr., "Central Limit Theorem" in "Probability,
           Random Variables and Random Signal Principles", 4th ed., 2001,
           pp. 51, 51, 125.
    Examples
    --------
    Draw samples from the distribution:
    >>> mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
    >>> s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
    Verify the mean and the variance:
    >>> abs(mu - np.mean(s)) < 0.01
    True
    >>> abs(sigma - np.std(s, ddof=1)) < 0.01
    True
    Display the histogram of the samples, along with
    the probability density function:
    >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    >>> count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 30, density=True)
    >>> plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *
    ...                np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),
    ...          linewidth=2, color='r')
    >>> plt.show()
    """
    cdef ndarray oloc, oscale
    cdef double floc, fscale

    oloc = <ndarray>PyArray_FROM_OTF(loc, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_ALIGNED)
    oscale = <ndarray>PyArray_FROM_OTF(scale, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_ALIGNED)

    if oloc.shape == oscale.shape == ():
        floc = PyFloat_AsDouble(loc)
        fscale = PyFloat_AsDouble(scale)
        if np.signbit(fscale):
            raise ValueError("scale < 0")
        return cont2_array_sc(self.internal_state, rk_normal, size, floc,
                              fscale, self.lock)

    if np.any(np.signbit(oscale)):
        raise ValueError("scale < 0")
    return cont2_array(self.internal_state, rk_normal, size, oloc, oscale,
                       self.lock)
```

As mentioned here in a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649802/finding-the-source-code-for-a-python-module?rq=1) (that I found after answering this) you can also try the following (but in this case it may not have gotten you much further than you did on your own):

```
import numpy.random
print(numpy.random.__file__)

# /home/adam/.pyenv/versions/datasci/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py
```

To trace the connection to `rk_gauss` you'll see `rk_normal` in the above code which links to:

```
double rk_normal(rk_state *state, double loc, double scale)
{
    return loc + scale*rk_gauss(state);
}
```

So its:

[Here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/464f79eb1d05bf938d16b49da1c39a4e02506fa3/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1551) to [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bb5d666e84e2eb294543a67c6143d7e9124d1c73/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c#L105) to [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2afa142ae6ee121f6c75f28403526e35473ee6d5/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L619). I think that's just a matter of seeing what other functions the function you are interested in calls.

Comment: The actual code for Box-Mueller is in the C file - https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2afa142ae6ee121f6c75f28403526e35473ee6d5/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L619
I want to know how this links to the method in the pyx file. Is this easy to trace?

Comment: Yes, `rk_normal` in `normal` and then you get https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bb5d666e84e2eb294543a67c6143d7e9124d1c73/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c#L105